# Cell subviews constraints changing programmatically in CellForRowAtIndex

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, nslayoutconstraint, custom-cell

I have a `UITableView`custom cell. It has a `UIView`and a `UIButton`
I want to change this view height constraint and the button's top constraint programmatically in my `cellForRowAtIndex. So Inside this im doing like this.

```
if(myintime2 == "00:00" && myoutTime2 == "00:00"  )
        {
            cell.btnIntime2.setTitle(myintime2, for: .normal)
            cell.btnOutTime2.setTitle(myoutTime2, for: .normal)

            cell.btnOutTime2.isHidden=true
            cell.btnIntime2.isHidden=true
            cell.customViewHeightConstraint.constant = 111
            cell.customBtnIn1Top.constant = 111/2


        }

        else if (myintime2 == "N/A" && myoutTime2 == "N/A")
        {
            cell.btnIntime2.setTitle(myintime2, for: .normal)
            cell.btnOutTime2.setTitle(myoutTime2, for: .normal)

            cell.btnOutTime2.isHidden=true
            cell.btnIntime2.isHidden=true
            cell.customViewHeightConstraint.constant = 111
            cell.customBtnIn1Top.constant = 111/2

        }


        else
        {
            cell.btnIntime2.setTitle(myintime2, for: .normal)
            cell.btnOutTime2.setTitle(myoutTime2, for: .normal)
            cell.customViewHeightConstraint.constant = 222
            cell.customBtnIn1Top.constant = 10
            cell.btnOutTime2.isHidden=false
            cell.btnIntime2.isHidden=false

        }
```

But some cells the height is wrong, please help me

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "some cells the height is wrong"? What is the expected result, what happens instead?

Comment: @mag_zbc I have to check 2 conditions.. if my in time2 is available I want to increase the height of the cell and increase the button's top constraint value. But when my condition doesnt satisfy cells are getting increased and top also getting increased.

Comment: @mag_zbc but not for all cells, this happens only for few cells. randomly

Comment: @mag_zbc And also when I scroll the tableview, then  some correct cells also getting wrong size

Comment: Try to clear the constraints before recreating the height

Comment: @AdrianaCarelli where can I clear my constraints?

Comment: it would be better set the height in method:  tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat

Answer (score 0):

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

         if(myintime2 == "00:00" && myoutTime2 == "00:00"  ){
                return 111
         }
        else if (myintime2 == "N/A" && myoutTime2 == "N/A")
        {
                return 111
         }else{
               return 222
         }

}
```

You can build multiple prototype cell by storyboard

[image]

Each type of cell creates it with a different height and with identifier different and not use constraints

[Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights?rq=1)

Comment: You mean I don't need to set height constraint for my subview?

Comment: it is a tableview, is not necessary set height constraint because exists this method when set the height of  cell

Comment: I changed it in your way. But now all the cells takes 308 which is my original cell size. :(

Comment: I changed inside heightforrowatIndex now height is changing but I dont understand how to update constraints of subviews

Comment: I changed inside heightforrowatIndex now height is changing but I dont understand how to update constraints of subviews